# Oracle: DBMS_LDAP. How to protect a password in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, security, passwords

I am using the oracle DBMS_LDAP module for a task and am needing to secure the process.

In the call to establish the session and connect, I need to provide a password.

```
  l_retval := DBMS_LDAP.simple_bind_s(ld     => l_session,
                                      dn     => l_ldap_user,
                                      passwd => l_ldap_passwd);
```

I also need to protect this password from anyone else getting at it... so how to do that?

I though I can put the password in a secured table.. may work. I need this procedure available to everyone though.. so I am not sure about how that may work.

I am not sure what my options are.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think you will ever be able to protect the password for "anyone else getting at it."  Regardless of the method, someone who as access to the PL/SQL code can just add a DBMS_OUTPUT line or write it to a table after the protected password is un-protected.  The first thing that popped into my head was Native Compilation.  I haven't used it, but I know that some vendors use it to hide their code.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap (obfuscate) your procedure utilizing the "wrap tool", but Oracle states:

*"Wrapping PL/SQL source text is not a secure way to hide passwords or table names. For high-assurance security, use Oracle Database Vault, described in Oracle Database Vault Administrator's Guide."*

```
create or replace procedure p
as
  l_password varchar2(100);
begin
  l_password := 'mysupersecretpassord';
end;
/

me@XE> @source p

SOURCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ME"."P" as   l_password varchar2(100);
begin   l_password := 'mysupersecretpassord'; end;


$ wrap iname=p.prc

PL/SQL Wrapper: Release 11.2.0.2.0- 64bit Production on Sun Jan 13 08:37:42 2013

Copyright (c) 1993, 2009, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Processing p.prc to p.plb

me@XE> @p.plb

Procedure created.

me@XE> @source p

SOURCE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "ME"."P" wrapped
a000000
369
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd

abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
abcd
7
5e 96
VoaqA4NZ8B46JZ/ptgsDoULsSlwwg5nnm7+fMr2ywFwWj8B0iwlp
pfQouHTLy/4owMznx3TA
M7h0ZSV8IXxQoIvAwDL+0oRcOAEKDkG6k3GjyKPDbuxxiaMJyFRxbg+JUUj
XQ/zB4Nempk3k
q6k=
```